# Concrete slopes away from drain

Tags: outdoor

Outside of my house the concrete slopes away from the drain causing the water to pool in a corner,any ideas to fix this ?

Answer (score 2):

- Add concrete (or asphalt patch) until the slope is to the drain,
- or break out concrete, possibly lower the drain, and replace concrete broken
  out with concrete that slopes properly to the drain.

A thin topcoat to correct the slope may not last for long, but it's easy to try for a start.

Breaking out and replacing will result in a thicker pour that's more likely to hold up through freeze/thaw cycles, if applicable to your location.

Comment: Assume a top coat will spall off in short order (just a few years) so when it last 5-10, you are happy, and when it lasts 2-5, you are still happy.  +1 for saying it may not last long.